# Sql Server Full-Text Index - File Extension

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Does the FileExtension column for Full-Text indexing have to be dot + extension? For example for a pdf it would be ".pdf" or can it be just "pdf"?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) seems to suggest the dot should be included:

> TYPE COLUMN type_column_name
>
> ...
>
> This column, known as the type
>   column, contains a user-supplied file extension (.doc, .pdf, .xls, and
>   so forth). The type column must be of type char, nchar, varchar, or
>   nvarchar.